# compiling GPL c source file and got Makefile error

Tags: compiling, gcc, makefile

I am trying to compile the GPL edition of a software Cubist on my Ubuntu machine.
I used the command `make all` to compile/execute the code,getting error message:

```
make cubist
make: /bin/csh: Command not found
Makefile:56: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 127
```

to make it clear here below i put the make file and `cubist.c` code 
Makefile

```
#*************************************************************************#
#*                                   *#
#*      Makefile for the Cubist system               *#
#*      ------------------------------               *#
#*                                   *#
#*************************************************************************#

CC  = gcc -ffloat-store
OFLAGS = -O3
CFLAGS = -DVerbOpt -g -Wall -O0
LFLAGS = $(S)
SHELL  = /bin/csh


#   Definitions of file sets
#   New file order suggested by gprof
src =\
    global.c\
    xval.c\
    cubist.c\
    sort.c\
    construct.c\
    predict.c\
    stats.c\
    discr.c\
    rules.c\
    contin.c\
    formrules.c\
    formtree.c\
    getdata.c\
    getnames.c\
    implicitatt.c\
    instance.c\
    modelfiles.c\
    prunetree.c\
    regress.c\
    trees.c\
    update.c\
    utility.c

obj =\
     global.o cubist.o construct.o\
     formtree.o prunetree.o stats.o discr.o contin.o\
     trees.o\
     formrules.o rules.o\
     instance.o\
     predict.o\
     regress.o\
     xval.o\
     getnames.o getdata.o implicitatt.o sort.o\
     modelfiles.o\
     update.o utility.o\


all:
    make cubist
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $(OFLAGS) -o summary summary.c -lm


# debug version (including verbosity option)

cubistdbg:\
    $(obj) defns.i extern.i text.i Makefile
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o cubistdbg $(obj) -lm


# production version

cubist:\
    $(src) defns.i text.i Makefile
    cat defns.i $(src)\
        | egrep -v 'defns.i|extern.i' >cubistgt.c
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $(OFLAGS) -o cubist cubistgt.c -lm
    strip cubist
    rm cubistgt.c


$(obj):     Makefile defns.i extern.i text.i


.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< 

cubist.c
/*************************************************************************/
/*                                   */
/*  Copyright 2010 Rulequest Research Pty Ltd.               */
/*                                   */
/*  This file is part of Cubist GPL Edition, a single-threaded version   */
/*  of Cubist release 2.07.                      */
/*                                   */
/*  Cubist GPL Edition is free software: you can redistribute it and/or  */
/*  modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as   */
/*  published by the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the   */
/*  License, or (at your option) any later version.          */
/*                                   */
/*  Cubist GPL Edition is distributed in the hope that it will be    */
/*  useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty  */
/*  of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the     */
/*  GNU General Public License for more details.             */
/*                                   */
/*  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License    */
/*  (gpl.txt) along with Cubist GPL Edition.  If not, see        */
/*                                   */
/*      <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.                  */
/*                                   */
/*************************************************************************/



/*************************************************************************/
/*                                   */
/*  Main routine, Cubist                         */
/*  --------------------                         */
/*                                   */
/*************************************************************************/


#include "defns.i"
#include "extern.i"

#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

#define SetOpt(V)   V = strtod(OptArg, &EndPtr);\
            if ( ! EndPtr || *EndPtr != '\00' ) break;\
            ArgOK = true
#define SetIOpt(V)  V = strtol(OptArg, &EndPtr, 10);\
            if ( ! EndPtr || *EndPtr != '\00' ) break;\
            ArgOK = true


int main(int Argc, char *Argv[])
/*  ----  */
{
    int         o;
    extern String   OptArg, Option;
    char        *EndPtr;
    Boolean     FirstTime=true, ArgOK;
    double      StartTime, SumCWt=0;
    FILE        *F;
    CaseNo      SaveMaxCase, i, NCWt=0;
    Attribute       Att;

    struct rlimit RL;

    /*  Make sure there is a largish runtime stack  */

    getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, &RL);

    RL.rlim_cur = Max(RL.rlim_cur, 20 * 1024 * 1024);

    if ( RL.rlim_max > 0 )  /* -1 if unlimited */
    {
    RL.rlim_cur = Min(RL.rlim_max, RL.rlim_cur);
    }

    setrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, &RL);

    /*  Check for output to be saved to a file  */

    if ( Argc > 2 && ! strcmp(Argv[Argc-2], "-o") )
    {
    Of = fopen(Argv[Argc-1], "w");
    Argc -= 2;
    }

    if ( ! Of )
    {
    Of = stdout;
    }

    KRInit = time(0) & 07777;
    StartTime = ExecTime();
    PrintHeader("");

    /*  Process options  */

    while ( (o = ProcessOption(Argc, Argv, "f+v+r+e+ian+uS+I+X+C+h")) )
    {
    if ( FirstTime )
    {
        fprintf(Of, T_OptHeader);
        FirstTime = false;
    }

    ArgOK = false;

    switch (o)
    {
    case 'f':   FileStem = OptArg;
            fprintf(Of, T_OptApplication, FileStem);
            ArgOK = true;
            break;
#ifdef VerbOpt
    case 'v':
            VERBOSITY = atoi(OptArg);
            fprintf(Of, "\tVerbosity level %d\n", VERBOSITY);
            ArgOK = true;
            break;
#endif
    case 'r':   SetIOpt(MAXRULES);
            fprintf(Of, T_OptMaxRules, MAXRULES);
            Check(MAXRULES, 1, 1000000);
            break;
    case 'e':   SetOpt(EXTRAP);
            fprintf(Of, T_OptExtrap, EXTRAP);
            Check(EXTRAP, 0, 100);
            EXTRAP /= 100;
            break;
    case 'i':   USEINSTANCES = true;
            fprintf(Of, T_OptUseInst);
            ArgOK = true;
            break;
    case 'a':   CHOOSEMODE = USEINSTANCES = true;
            fprintf(Of, T_OptAllowInst);
            ArgOK = true;
            break;
    case 'n':   USEINSTANCES = true;
            SetIOpt(NN);
            fprintf(Of, TX_NNeighbors(NN));
            Check(NN, 1, NNMAX);
            ArgOK = true;
            break;
    case 'u':   UNBIASED = true;
            fprintf(Of, T_NoBias);
            ArgOK = true;
            break;
    case 'S':   SetOpt(SAMPLE);
                fprintf(Of, T_OptSampling, SAMPLE);
                Check(SAMPLE, 0.1, 99.9);
                SAMPLE /= 100;
                break;
    case 'I':   SetIOpt(KRInit);
            fprintf(Of, T_OptSeed, KRInit);
            KRInit = KRInit & 07777;
            break;
    case 'X':   SetIOpt(FOLDS);
                fprintf(Of, T_OptXval, FOLDS);
                Check(FOLDS, 1, 1000);
            XVAL = true;
                break;
    case 'C':   SetIOpt(MEMBERS);
                fprintf(Of, T_OptCttee, MEMBERS);
                Check(MEMBERS, 1, 100);
                break;
    }

    if ( ! ArgOK )
    {
        if ( o != 'h' )
        {
        fprintf(Of, T_UnregnizedOpt, Option,
                ( ! OptArg || OptArg == Option+2 ? "" : OptArg ));
        fprintf(Of, T_SummaryOpts);
        }
        fprintf(Of, T_ListOpts);
        Goodbye(1);
    }
    }

    /*  Get information on training data  */

    if ( ! (F = GetFile(".names", "r")) ) Error(NOFILE, "", "");
    GetNames(F);

    fprintf(Of, T_TargetAtt, AttName[ClassAtt]);

    NotifyStage(READDATA);
    Progress(-1.0);

    if ( ! (F = GetFile(".data", "r")) ) Error(NOFILE, "", "");
    GetData(F, true, false);
    fprintf(Of, TX_ReadData(MaxCase+1, MaxAtt, FileStem));

    if ( XVAL && (F = GetFile(".test", "r")) )
    {
    SaveMaxCase = MaxCase;
    GetData(F, false, false);
    fprintf(Of, TX_ReadTest(MaxCase-SaveMaxCase, FileStem));
    }

    /*  Check whether case weight attribute appears.  If it does,
    normalize values to average 1, and replace N/A values and
    values <= 0 with average value 1  */

    if ( CWtAtt )
    {
    fprintf(Of, T_CWtAtt);

    /*  Find average case weight value  */

    ForEach(i, 0, MaxCase)
    {
        if ( ! NotApplic(Case[i], CWtAtt) && CVal(Case[i], CWtAtt) > 0 )
        {
        SumCWt += CVal(Case[i], CWtAtt);
        NCWt += 1;
        }
    }

    AvCWt = ( NCWt > 0 ? SumCWt / NCWt : 1 );

    ForEach(i, 0, MaxCase)
    {
        if ( ! NotApplic(Case[i], CWtAtt) && CVal(Case[i], CWtAtt) > 0 )
        {
        CVal(Case[i], CWtAtt) /= AvCWt;
        }
        else
        {
        CVal(Case[i], CWtAtt) = 1;
        }
    }
    }
    else
    {
    AvCWt = 1;
    }

    /*  Note any attribute exclusions/inclusions  */

    if ( AttExIn )
    {
    fprintf(Of, "%s", ( AttExIn == -1 ? T_AttributesOut : T_AttributesIn ));

    ForEach(Att, 1, MaxAtt)
    {
        if ( ( StatBit(Att, SKIP) > 0 ) == ( AttExIn == -1 ) )
        {
        fprintf(Of, "    %s\n", AttName[Att]);
        }
    }
    }

    /*  Build and evaluate cubist model  */

    InitialiseEnvData();

    if ( XVAL )
    {
    CrossVal();
    }
    else
    {
    SingleCttee();
    }

#ifdef VerbOpt
    Cleanup();
#endif

    fprintf(Of, T_Time, ExecTime() - StartTime);

    return 0;
}
```

I admire any Help, Thank you very much.

Comment: At the beginning of the makefile, `SHELL=/bin/csh`defines `csh`to be the shell to execute (see https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html). You should install: `sudo install csh`.

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved my day:: after installing the csh the make file worked for me(created executable file) . nevertheless when i try to compile the .c file individually with gcc -o cubist cubist.c it prone a lot of error "undefined reference to "here below is the error

Comment: I think this is the reason why the executable file created by makefile  does not does the expected task.  could you please help me how to tackle this problem .here below is the error     In function `main':
cubist.c:(.text+0xbab): undefined reference to `Of'                               
cubist.c:(.text+0x10f): undefined reference to `KRInit'
cubist.c:(.text+0x114): undefined reference to `ExecTime'
cubist.c:(.text+0x17a): undefined reference to `OptArg'
cubist.c:(.text+0x181): undefined reference to `FileStem'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Of course. The makefile `cat`s `defns.i` and all source files to an intermediate file `cubistgt.c`(removing the local `#include`s) and then compiles that one, i.e., all sources are compiled as one source file. Otherwise, you had to compile all .c-files to .o-files and then link them to one executable. To help in more details is beyond the scope of  _askUbuntu_; you should post the question on some programmer's Q&A

Comment: Thank you, But what do you mean by compile all .c file into one executable

Comment: Post this question on StackOverflow. And try to understand how `make` and building executables in Linux work.